# How to disable a date range in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to disable a range of dates which I are fetched using Ajax. I'm doing it as follows -

```
$("#date_frm").datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
 constrainInput: true,
 beforeShow:function(input, inst) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/get_time_span",
            data: "",
            success: function(data) {
             disabled_day = data;
            },  
        });
 },
 beforeShowDay: disableRangeOfDays 
 });

 function disableRangeOfDays(d) 
 {
    //var arr = "2012-04-19 to 2012-04-26,";
    var arr = disabled_day.split(",");
    var arr = arr.split(",");
    var cnt = arr.length-1;
    for(i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
        arr1 = arr[i].split(" to ");
        //create date for from_date
        frm_dt = arr1[0].split('-');
        //create date for to_date
        to_dt = arr1[1].split('-');
        if(d >= new Date(frm_dt[0],(frm_dt[1]-1),frm_dt[2]) && 
d <= new Date(to_dt[0],(to_dt[1]-1),to_dt[2])) {
                return [false];
            } 
        }
        return [true,''];
      }
```

This works but not for the first time. When I open the date picker first time,  the date range still selectable. But, after I close and reopen it, the date range is disabled. Also, if I change the month and come back to the current month then also it works. How can I disable the date range for the first time I open the date picker ? Also, for each month, I want to fetch the date ranges and disable them. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

After spending much time in checking possibilities, I fetched all the date ranges only once while loading the page and assigned all to a hidden field. I removed the Ajax call and used the value of the hidden field directly in the  function **disableRangeOfDays(d)** and it worked as expected.